# Uiautomator - takeScreenshot - is there a way to store the image on the machine running the tests instead of the device

Tags: android-uiautomator

In a uiautomator test, using takeScreenshot(), is there a way to store the image on the machine running the tests instead of the device?

If it cant be done with takeScreenshot, id be interested in hearing any alternative methods anyone has come up with.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a store path (screenPath) and save the screenshot on the device.

The you could use adb pull like this:

```
adb pull screenPath localPath
```

To copy the screenshot locally.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet fully covering all *UiAutomator* cases but [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) could give you an alternative. You may replace some of your tests and take screenshots and they will be saved on the machine running the tests.

There's a extremely simple way of generating test cases using [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI), just run:

```
$ culebra -UG -o mytest.py
```

to generate a test case. Then, during the test generation, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (or the context menu) and the screenshot will be saved and a line like this

```
self.vc.writeImageToFile('/tmp/${serialno}-${focusedwindowname}-${timestamp}.png', 'PNG')
```

will be generated in the test script, so everytime you run it will be saved without overriting the previous one.

Hope this helps.